vscode file nseting pattern getting applied to internal folder also; how to exclude to do so?
vscode version: 1.95.3
os: MacOS
below seetings in vscode ( in workspace file )
"explorer.fileNesting.enabled": true,
"explorer.fileNesting.expand": false,
"explorer.fileNesting.patterns": {
      "*.js": "${capture}.js.map, ${capture}.min.js, ${capture}.d.ts",
      "*.jsx": "${capture}.js",
      "*.ts": "${capture}.js",
      "*.tsx": "${capture}.ts",
      "package.json": "package-lock.json",
      "readme.md": "*.md",
      "tsconfig.json": "tsconfig.*.json, jsconfig.json"
}

which does good job but now issue is, having a docs folder and under that there is README.md and other markdown (.md) files but I do not want file nesting to be applied there and setting only be applicable on project root
is there any way we can do?

I think there're no way to do this. So, Configure file Nesting pattern as follows:
"explorer.fileNesting.enabled": true,
"explorer.fileNesting.expand": false,
"explorer.fileNesting.patterns": {
      "*.js": "${capture}.js.map, ${capture}.min.js, ${capture}.d.ts",
      "*.jsx": "${capture}.js",
      "*.ts": "${capture}.js",
      "*.tsx": "${capture}.ts",
      "package.json": "package-lock.json",
      "readme.md": "CHANGELOGO.md, todo.md",
      "tsconfig.json": "tsconfig.*.json, jsconfig.json"
}


No, but this needs everytime  require update whenever add new md file in project root
